# Find Some sample examples for parsing of wsdl url using wsdl4j

Tags: parsing, wsdl4j

Please somebody help me to find some sample examples for parsing for wsdl url using wsdl4j API.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try like this;

```
public Definition readWSDLFile() throws  WSDLException {
        WSDLReader reader = getWsdlFactoryInstance().newWSDLReader();
        // switch off the verbose mode
        reader.setFeature(JAVAX_WSDL_VERBOSE_MODE, false);
        reader.setFeature("javax.wsdl.importDocuments", true);

        Definition wsdlDefinition;
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Reading  the WSDL. Base uri is " + baseURI);
        }
        wsdlDefinition = reader.readWSDL(baseURI);
        return wsdlDefinition;

    }
```

Using the Definition you can access the operation, service objects.. to access a service address location;

```
private void setServiceDefinition(Definition definition) throws Exception {

        Map serviceMap = definition.getAllServices();
        Iterator serviceItr = serviceMap.entrySet().iterator();
        URL addressURI = null;
        try {
            while (serviceItr.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry svcEntry = (Map.Entry) serviceItr.next();
                Service svc = (Service) svcEntry.getValue();
                Map portMap = svc.getPorts();
                Iterator portItr = portMap.entrySet().iterator();
                while (portItr.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry portEntry = (Map.Entry) portItr.next();
                    Port port = (Port) portEntry.getValue();
                    ExtensibilityElement extensibilityElement = (ExtensibilityElement) port.getExtensibilityElements()
                                                                                           .get(0);

                    addressURI = new URL(getAddressUrl(extensibilityElement));

                }
            }
```

Here is a [sample](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/11/get-wsdl-service-address-with-wsdl4j.html) i have written, May be useful to you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.